# Can these statements be written more concisely?

Tags: javascript, typescript, refactoring

Can these statements be written more concisely?

```
if (o.desc != null) {
    service.do(a, {name: o.name, desc: o.desc})
}
else {
    service.do(a, {name: o.name})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work?

```
service.do(a, {name: o.name, desc: o.desc})
```

Comment: It will still keep desc as undefined, but wouldn't completely get rid of the property itself.

Answer (score 0):

Can try this one :-

```
 var param =
 !o.desc? {name: o.name} : {name: o.name, desc: o.desc}

 service.do(a, param)
```